# What cool features/applications are there to change the way ubuntu GUI interface looks and feels?

Tags: icons, gui, interface, personalization

I'm new to ubuntu, and was just curious of things that I can do with this OS (ex: changing folder icons, button icons, etc.). I know this isn't really a technical question, more of a fun one. What kind of stuff do you guys do to personalize your computers? I don't think there is a "correct" answer on this topic. lol. Thanks :)

Comment: This is much big to answer. Please be more specific in your question, moreover I think you can find all of your needs already asked and answered here in askubuntu. So just take a tour and search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first there is standard settings , go to the System settings and Personal box which have Appearance , where you can change theme , size of icons and wallpapers.

Here you will find new icons and themes : [Deviant Art](http://deviantart.com)
If you want more customize install with console Ubuntu Tweak:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Or Unity Tweak Tools:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Comment: also you if you don`t know how to do all of this you can watch video for example this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inZ9uYYILXU